# Outer measure - prove that if $\mu_{\star}(B)=0$ then $\mu_{\star}(A \cup B) =\mu_{\star}(A \cap B) = \mu_{\star}(A)$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu_{\star}$ be outer measure on set $X$ and $A,B \subset X$. Furthermore $\mu_{\star}(B)=0$. Prove that $$\mu_{\star}(A \cup B) =\mu_{\star}(A \cap B) = \mu_{\star}(A)$$

- $\mu_{\star}(A \cup B) =\mu_{\star}(A)$
  This case is easy because from definition we have $\mu_{\star}(A \cup B) \le \mu_{\star}(A) + \mu_{\star}(B) = \mu_{\star}(A)$. Because $A \subset A \cup B$ then we have $\mu_{\star}(A) \le \mu_{\star}(A \cup B)$
- Now I should show that $\mu_{\star}(A \cup B) = \mu_{\star}(A \cap B)$ or $\mu_{\star}(A \cap B)=\mu_{\star}(A)$. It is obviously that $\mu_{\star}(A \cap B) \le \mu_{\star}(A \cup B)$ and $\mu_{\star}(A \cap B) \le \mu_{\star}(A)$. So finally I have to show that $\mu_{\star}(A \cap B) \ge \mu_{\star}(A \cup B)$ or $\mu_{\star}(A \cap B) \ge \mu_{\star}(A)$.

Do you have any idea how can I get it?

By the way, furthermore I noticed that $A \cap B \subset B$ so $\mu_{\star}(A \cap B) \le \mu_{\star}(B) = 0$ and of course $\mu_{\star}(A \cap B) \ge 0$. Hence  $\mu_{\star}(A \cap B) =0$. So we can say that in this task $\mu_{\star}(A \cup B) =\mu_{\star}(A \cap B) = \mu_{\star}(A)=0$?

I will really grateful for your help.

Comment: Since there is no reason to expect $\mu_\star(A) = 0$, I think the task is to show $\mu_\star(A\setminus B) = \mu_\star(A)$. Since $A\setminus B = A \cap B^c$, where $B^c$ denotes the complement of $B$, it seems at some point the ${}^c$ got lost.

Comment: Ok so now the problem is to show that $\mu_{\star} (A \setminus B) \ge \mu_{\star} (A)$ (or $\mu_{\star} (A \setminus B) \ge \mu_{\star} (A \cup B)$. Intuitively I see it because measure of $B$ is zero. But how prove it more formal? Could you give me some hints?

Comment: Consider $(A\setminus B) \cup B$.

Comment: Ok, now all is clear. But now, also we have that $\mu_{\star}(A \cap B) = 0$ yes?

Comment: Yes, $0 \leqslant \mu_\star(A\cap B) \leqslant \mu_\star(B)$.